# Why in QtCreator file ui_xxx.h is kept as top secret?

Tags: qt5, qt-creator

When working with QtCreator, I do some mistake. The compiler finds it and presents with error message

```
Object::connect: No such slot RegisterWidget::OctalR_clicked() in ./ui_registerwidget.h:65
Object::connect:  (sender name:   'OctalButton')
Object::connect:  (receiver name: 'RegisterWidget')
```

In my source file

```
#include "ui_registerwidget.h"
```

is explicitly present. I receive the error message, with reference to a line of a source header which does not exist. OK, I understand that it is generated on the fly, and that I can generate it using `uic`, and this way I can see what is the problem. What I do not understand, why this way of handling this file is good for me, during debugging?